# Get a random negative value in java

Tags: java, random

I want to apport a random change to a float.The change should be in a range of -0.3 and +0.3 percent. So i need a nember between -0.3 and 0.3

```
float value = 133;
    java.util.Random rand = new java.util.Random();
    int al = rand.nextInt(300);
    float perc = al / 100; //How to get value mit rest 2.7 for example and how to get negative values
   System.out.println ("random perc "+ perch); 
   value = value + (value * perc) / 100;
```

how can I get a negative value in nextInt and how can I get a float random value ?

Comment: What do you mean by "a range of -0.3 and +0.3 percent"? The value of the variable is just going to be in numbers... do you mean you want a range of `[-0.3, 0.3)` or `[-0.003, 0.003)`?

Comment: (In general, this sounds like you want something like `random.nextDouble() * 0.6 - 0.3` though.)

Comment: try al = 300 - rand.nextInt(600)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
int al = rand.nextInt(600) - 300
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `100` to `100.0F`. This allows floating point arithmetric for `/` operator.

```
float perc = al / 100.0F;
```

You can also get the negative value using the unary operator `-`.

```
float perc = - al / 100.0F;
```

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. The OP wants to generate a random number between -0.3 and 0.3

Comment: @MaxMeijer Actually, he specifically asked "how can I get a negative value in nextInt and how can I get a float random value ?".

Comment: He says that he wants a number in the range from -0.3 and 0.3. He is a bit unclear but he means "how can I get also negative values in nextInt and how can I get a float random value?"

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
 random.nextFloat()*6 - 3
```

This will return a number between -3 and 3

Comment: I need a number bteween -3.00 and 3.00

Comment: @user3697171 then you should edit your title so it makes more sense

Comment: @user3697171 Still think this works... and Wim yes yes that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

Manipulating your random output is fairly simple. For instance if you want to get a number between -100 and 100, that's the same as getting a number between 0 and 200 but subtracting 100. Similarly, if you want to get a number between 0 and -200, you can either subtract 200 (remember this is outside of the random generation) or you can multiply by -1. 
To get a `float` instead of an `int` use `rand.nextFloat()` instead of `rand.nextInt()`
Cheers